# How to make Autosending Telegram bot aiogram

Tags: python, bots, telegram, aiogram

How to make automatic sending of messages in the telegram bot daily at a certain time (10:00), as well as weekly on Sundays at 20:00

Aiogram

I tried to implement it through the schedule module, but it gives an error when sending a message

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import asyncio
import aioschedule

async def noon_print():
    print("It's noon!")

async def scheduler():
    aioschedule.every().day.at("12:00").do(noon_print)
    while True:
        await aioschedule.run_pending()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def on_startup(_):
    asyncio.create_task(scheduler())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False, on_startup=on_startup)
```

Comment: is the 12:00 as per UTC?